# Data points overlapped with each other on zoom out in arcgis map

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api, angular11

I am using an arcgis(Esri) maps to show the data. I have too many data points. When i am doing zoom out these data points are getting overlapped with each other. Not sure how i can deal with this.

Please note I am using graphics layer in my map.

Answer (score 1):

In 3D (JSAPI 4.x) we have the declutter option in the SceneView (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-FeatureReductionSelection.html). In 2D there is clustering (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#featureReduction)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I figured it and implemented using feature layer and feature reduction.